# Magento /no-route URL

Tags: magento-1.9, url

After looking at the log files of my Magento site, I noticed that a URL ending *.co.uk/no-route* was getting a significant number of events.

What is this URL?

Comment: if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Any URL in Magento which does not find target page those URL will be considered as a (no-route) **404 Page**

In Magento, such pages are called **no-route** (means for which routing is not available)

Simply all 404 request will be considered as **no-route** URL.

Comment: is it okay to set to homepage instead of no-route page? as seo point of view?

Comment: Yes  I have some of store which redirects you to home page in case of 404 :)

Answer (score 1):

Magento default installation already has a predefined custom `404 page` (no-route).

Under Magento administration we can manually set default 404 page template.

> System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Pages -> CMS No
>   Route Page.

Here you can add any previously created CMS page (Customer Services for example).

[image]

Default `404 page` settings

Or you can use more specific content (search form, store sitemap, contact form, specific store categories with promoted products…).

I hope it will clear your concern.

Comment: If you want to redirect to the homepage is it not better to replace with empty value or just a slash? Would be nice ot update the answer after we know this.